# upload file to ftp c#

Tags: c#, web, ftp

im trying to upload a file to ftp server and i keep getting "webexception unable to connect to the remote server 530 not logged in"

dose anyone know how to fix this problem?
u tryied to disable my fire wall but it has no effect

```
 /* Create an FTP Request */
                FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpurl + "/" + remoteFile);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpuser, ftppassword,ftpurl);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
              Stream  ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
                /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
                FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
                /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */

                {
                    while (bytesSent != 0)
                    {
                        ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                        bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                }

                /* Resource Cleanup */
                localFileStream.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
```

Comment: have you verified the contents of user/pw/url ?

Comment: **not logged in** - supply the correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NetworkCredential` seems to be wrong. The third parameter sets the domain (See: [NetworkCredential Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cytcd70k.aspx)). Try changing it to :

```
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpuser, ftppassword);
```

Comment: i tryied it now i get anoter webexception that just say system error

Comment: @dna - you can use all three, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cytcd70k.aspx

Comment: @DarthVader sure you can, but using the FTP url as the domain name is obviously wrong

Comment: @user1839169 Where the exception occurs?

Comment: Stream  ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();

Comment: Have you try to set the request `ContentLength` before calling `GetRequestStream()`?

See the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getrequeststream.aspx